# How can I return an object from a ArrayList?

Tags: java

I would like to return the *Host* thats have the same **domain** as the *Host* in the List. But it gives me and error: *"This method have to return a type of Host"*.

How I have to return the object *Host*?

```
public class Manager {

private List<Host> hosts = new ArrayList<Host>();

public Host getHost (String domain) {

      for(int i = 0; i < hosts.size(); i++) {
          if(domain == hosts.get(i).getDomain()) {
              return hosts.get(i);
          }}      
  }
```

Thanks.

Comment: use `.equals` not `==` to compare strings, `domain.equals(hosts.get(i).getDomain())`

Comment: The problem is that you cannot be sure that your loop and if statement will be entered at all. You need to define a return statement in case the current return statement isn't reached.

Comment: or throw an exception if not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to return null after your loop.

```
  public Host getHost (String domain) {
        for(int i = 0; i < hosts.size(); i++) {
            if(domain.equals(hosts.get(i).getDomain())) {
              return hosts.get(i);
            }
        }      
        return null;
    }
```

You can also throw an Exception if nothing found.

Answer (score 2):

First, to compare `String` you need to use `String.equals`

```
if(domain.equals(hosts.get(i).getDomain()))
```

Second, you don't return something if this is not found, you need to either return `null` or throw an exception

```
 for(int i = 0; i < hosts.size(); i++) {
     ...
 }
 return null;
```

or

```
 for(int i = 0; i < hosts.size(); i++) {
     ...
 }
 throw new ItemNotFoundException(); //Or any exception you want
```

Answer (score 2):

What about `stream` and `Optional`

```
return hosts.stream().filter(host -> host.getDomain().equals(domain)).findAny();
```

result type will be `Optinal<Host>`

Comment: Seems a bit complicate if OPs don't know how to compare a `String` but nice solution. Isn't there also a `findFirst` or something ?

Comment: @AxelH, yes it might be a bit complicated. Yes, there is `findFirst` which will return exactly the fist element, `findAny` will return any element with match the condition.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be because the last line in your method is not a return? Maybe try this:

```
public Host getHost (String domain) {
      Host host = null;
      for(int i = 0; i < hosts.size(); i++) {
          if(domain.equals(hosts.get(i).getDomain())) {
              //saves in the variable declared outside of for
              host = hosts.get(i);
          }
      }
      //attention: if nothing is found in your arraylist, the returned object is refers to null
      return host;
  }
```